# Infinite redirects between Identity Server and Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I've got the following client set up in IdentityServer:

```
internal class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Client",
                ClientName = "Client",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("blablabla".Sha256())},

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { Startup.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Clients", "https://localhost:5002") + "/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { Startup.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Clients", "https://localhost:5002") + "/signout-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "roles",
                    "Business-to-Business-users",
                    "reporting-urls"
                },

                RequirePkce = true,
                AllowPlainTextPkce = false,

                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
               
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify the mvc client to login to the above identity server. In startup.cs I modified **cllientID**, **ClientSecret** and **Authority** to match the client settings.  This is my ConfigureServices():

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie("cookie")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityHost", "https://localhost:5000");
                options.ClientId = "Client";
                options.ClientSecret = "blablabla";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.UsePkce = true;
                options.ResponseMode = "query";
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.Scope.Add("Business-to-Business-users");
                options.Scope.Add("reporting-urls");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("Business-to-Business-user", "Business-to-Business-user");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("reporting-url", "reporting-url");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "role",
                };
            });
```

first I got a bug that he needs https but instead uses http. So I added the following code to my Configure:

```
            app.Use((context, next) => {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        });
```

Now that this error was solved, I ran into a different one.
As soon as I'm trying to login to my client, I got the following error in my browser (Opera): "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".
Does anyone have an idea how I can proceed? Both Identity and the client are seperate docker containers.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post a sample request that causes the redirect, perhaps using a tool like Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Also post a copy of your Startup.Configure method. Perhaps       app.UseHttpsRedirection(); is confused due to the app.Use((context, next).... you mentioned in the question.